# Can't Get IEnumerable of Inherited Class in LINQ Query

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq

I am trying to convert some code from VB over to C# and have had an extremely hard time with this particular LINQ query. First I'll show the classes:

```vb
Public Class CompanyData
        Property CompanyID As String = ""
        Property VendorNumber As String = ""
        Property VendorName As String = ""

End Class

Public Class MultiCompData
        Inherits CompanyData

        Property ExpCompanyId As String = ""
End Class
```

Then in the VB example what it does is Group all into MultiCompData in a multiCompGroup field, foreach through it and add to a different list of CompanyData if ExpCompanyId is null/empty. Code:

```vb
Sub ProcessMultiCompData(multiCompDataJEs As IEnumerable(Of MultiCompData), ByRef multiCompData As List(Of CompanyData), ByRef undeterminedDists As List(Of CompanyData))

    Dim multiCompGroups =
        From m In multiCompDataJEs
        Group m By m.ExpCompanyId,
                   m.VendorNumber,
                   m.VendorName
        Into Group

    For Each grp In multiCompGroups
        If grp.ExpCompanyId = "" Then

            undeterminedDists.AddRange(grp.Group)
```

In the foreach, grp has the following properties - ExpCompanyId, VendorNumber, VendorName and Group (which is the part I can't replicate in C#) Group being an IEnumerable. Is it not possible to add that IEnumerable in C# to multiCompGroups?? I have tried:

```cs
var multiCompGroups = from m in multiCompDataJEs group by new {m.ExpCompanyiD, m.VendorNumber, m.VendorName} into multiGroups
```

multiGroups doesn't show up as an IEnumerable in my grp value when I get to the foreach, i've also tried it this way:

```cs
var multiCompGroups = multiCompDataJEs.GroupBy(x => new {m.ExpCompanyId, m.VendorNumber, m.VendorName}).Select(y => new {y.Key.ExpCompanyId, y.Key.VendorNumber, y.Key.VendorName}).ToList();
```

Both are producing the same thing. I have the 3 properties show up when I do grp. but the "Into Group" (grp.Group in the VB code above) doesn't show up in C#. Is it even possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C# you're looking for is:

```
var multiCompGroups =
    from m in multiCompDataJEs
    group m by new {m.ExpCompanyiD, m.VendorNumber, m.VendorName} into multiGroups
    select multiGroups;

foreach(var grp in multiCompGroups)
{
    if(grp.Key.ExpCompanyId == "")
    {
        undeterminedDists.AddRange(grp);
    }
}
```